# How to get actual font a character is using on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, fonts

First, I know those:

- [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) and its [unicode-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range),
- [CSS Fonts Module Level 3 - 5.2. Matching font styles](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-fonts-3-20180920/#font-style-matching)
- [FontForge](https://fontforge.org/) (Free, Open Source Font Editor) to create self-made characters ([Private-Use Characters](http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html)) in [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_%28Unicode%29). (PS: It seems that markdown files in VSCode cannot load private-use characters in ttf but in woff.)
- Private Character Editor (eudcedit.exe) on windows to customize rarely-used Chinese characters (not included in the Unicode standard). It is simple but it doesn't seem for me to [get the stored file](http://Private%20Character%20Editor%20(EUDCEDIT)%20data%20storing%20Q).

I roughly understand the rule for choosing a font for a given character. Howerver, if failed, when falling back on CSS Web Safe Fonts from OS (**system font fallback**), how can I know which font wins in the end?

I used Chrome and font choice affects printing.

The below code (or Open the "Element" tab of the Chrome devtool, select "Computed" and check "show all") is not what I want because it outputs `font-family:"Times New Roman";` for Chinese characters.

```js
/*
reusable code to get the property value of any element with an id

call the function, passing in element id and the style property that
you want to know
*/

function getStylePropertyValue(elemId, prop) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
  return window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue(prop);
}

//getComputedStyle(temp1).getPropertyValue('font-family');
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/kekkou/pen/MzYzoo)

Comment: I tried [Firefox Browser Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) 73.0b5 (64-bit). It could show Fonts Used in devtool and display a large HTML faster (60 seconds / 285 A4 pages vs 10 seconds / 316 A4 pages). But, layouts differed (285 vs 316 because I didn't specify the font). Besides, FF used system print dialog. After picked "Microsoft Print to PDF" in "Select Printer", the output PDF file is too big. the output PDF file is relatively small for "Save as PDF" in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think FontFaceSet.check() could be an option.

you could know which font is available or not.

[FontFaceSet.check()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check)

Comment: Good API, but, unfortunately, `document.fonts.check('16px "Times New Roman"', '秦始皇')` returns `true`. Moreover, "Times New Roman" (C:\Windows\Fonts\times.ttf) opened in FontForge doesn't contain Chinese characters. It seems the availability checking is unlikelihood (Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)).